# npm module installation is not picking the current package to install

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

Getting this weird error while installing expo-modules-core. I have clean the npm cache but it keeps giving me Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/react-navigation-reanimated - Not found 404 error. Although I'm not installing it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My package.json file mistakenly contains this wrong package name i.e. react-navigation-reanimated, its react-native-reanimated actually. Removing that from the package.json removed the error.